# GAE python asyncore issue

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, fcntl

I was trying to use pyDNS on GAE.

In Base.py there is `import asyncore`

Thats what I get:

```
 File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/lib/DNS/Base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import asyncore
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 608, in <module>
    import fcntl
ImportError: No module named fcntl
```

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If the library implementations meets the GAE restrictions you can include it and upload it to GAE as part of your application.

Here are the official instructions for [Adding Third-party Packages to the Application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring) (sometimes called `vendoring` it in).

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is nothing to do about this, besides avoiding modules that depend on unsupported modules.

GAE just does not support **fcntl** spawning threads module.